# Flutter ListView hard to scroll because gestured children's onTap property

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm using `GesturedDetector` + `Container` in ListView as children, and it works fine.
but sometimes it's hard to scroll if I touch the Children when scroll.

Because GestureDetector detects my scrolling as tap, so the whole ListView doesn't scroll. 
If I change the onTap to `onLongPress`, it solved, but not what I want.

So, Is there any great solution to my situation?

Now I only have an idea that makes children's margin bigger, reducing the chance that children are being touched.

Comment: where is the code?

Comment: Please share your code. We will not be able to help you otherwise. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thanks you for responding

Comment: It was solved by adding behavior,really appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried the following code to try to reproduce your issue but it doesn't happen. When I drag the ListView moves up and down, when I tap it prints the String. Try this code on your app to see if the issue also happens.

```
ListView(
  children: List.generate(50, (index) {
    return GestureDetector(
      behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent, // You can try adding this to help
      onTap: () => print('item $index'),
      child: Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: Text('item $index'),
        height: 40,
      ),
    );
  }),
)
```

Comment: Please remember to mark the answer as correct, so that other users can find it.